# What are the rules that the teachers in Hogwarts should comply to?

Tags: harry-potter

The teachers seem to be free to do anything, short from killing someone. Well also THIS happens and Snape gets away with it but we can be explained with the political situation.

So the teachers may:

1. Decide how to teach and what to teach in their classes. Examples:

   - All DADA teachers had completely different style and content to teach
   - Hagrid teaches whatever he finds interesting
   - When Snape steps in for Lupin as DADA teacher he just decides to start a lesson about werewolves. While he does this out of malice, it again shows that the teachers do whatever they want.
   - Some teachers are more or less incompetent: Lockhart, Trelawney, Quirrell
2. Award and take points from students on WHATEVER reason they find appropriate. Examples (there are lots of them but just giving the most extreme ones):

   - Snape taking points from Hermione just because she wants to answer a question that he asked (first Potions class in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*).
   - Flitwick awarding points for very simple tasks in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* (as a protest against Umbridge's rules)
   - Snape taking points from Stebbins and Fawcett for (presumably) making out in the dark after the Yule Ball
3. Give ANY form of detention to students. Usually the detention is not proportional to the violation done. The most extreme examples again:

   - Sending Harry, Neville, Hermione and Malfoy into the forest during the night. Honestly that could be considered pure murder if something happened to them.
   - Writing lines with their own blood (Umbridge to Harry)
   - Answering fan letters (Lockhart to Harry). While not anything dangerous Lockhart is just using a kid to do his personal chores.
   - Umbridge forbidding Harry, Fred and George from playing Quidditch (although she had special permissions in this case).

Comment: Hagrid may seem to just teach whatever he wants during his sessions, but during the pre-OWLS period, it becomes clear that he's actually provided them with a solid overview of the likely subjects that are assessed.

Comment: re: Snape standing in for Lupin. Substitute teachers will often use pre-prepared lessons rather than following the  existing syllabus that the main teacher was using. These are known as "flat-pack" lessons. Note also that Lupin may have been avoiding the subject of Werewolves so as not to give his students too many clues.

Comment: I've voted to close as too broad. It seems like you're looking for someone to present you with a book called "Handbook for Teachers at Hogwarts".

Comment: I'd buy that book (and use it for my own teaching)

Comment: Even a list of rules that teachers must adhere to in a public high school would be a good sized book, let alone a magical school. This topic seems to broad.

Comment: Actually the list at Hogwarts seems to be shorter (at least according to canon sources) - "Do whatever you want and if you screw up we'll see. And by the way don't be a half-breed because this might get you fired."

Comment: Detention and punishments certainly weren’t unrestricted. Witness Filch’s complaints about not being able to hang students by the wrist, or use whips, or McGonagall reprimanding Moody for using transfiguration on Malfoy.